# Tool for transforming variables of different types in Java

Tags: java, refactoring, type-conversion, transform

Suppose I want to perform some non-trivial(not just though type casting) transformations for a variable v, e.g.,  from type T1(String) to T2(List):

```
String v = "123";
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

One solution will be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
    char c = v.charAt(i);
    int intVal = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    list.add(intVal);
}
```

However, if the transformations are performed among various types, manually permuting solutions for all the patterns will be both tedious and  inefficient.

The question is, is there any tool to do this kind of transformation automatically?

Thanks,

Comment: no, but you can develop that tool :)

Comment: if the transformations are performed among various types??Didnt quite get it. can you explain it further with example

Comment: The question is **why** would you like to do that? Such conversions usually indicate poor application design.

Comment: I really hope there is no tool that is able to automatically generate all the possible ways of transforming input of an arbitrary type to output of an arbitrary type. Because then we'll all be out of our lovely paying jobs.

Comment: No, there isn't, and there really shouldn't be.  You should be explicit about how exactly you want to do this conversion.  (You can do this sort of thing much more compactly with Java 8 streams, though.)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. We are trying our best to avoid this kind of conversions(Even for type cast) in a well design system. However, at the end of the day, you have to write a few kind of "adapter code" to communicate with other APIs which is not own by yourself. e.g., You want to pass a LinkedList of ints to a quicksort function but its argument is an array of doubles. I am wondering whether we could tackle this issue in a bit more general way instead of an ad-hoc manner.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are asking for, (im assuming a sort of catch-all typecasting tool that could work for almost anything) doesn't exist. It wouldn't really make sense for something like that to be built in because there are so many different ways people would want some object to be represented in other formats.

If you wanted to have a tool to transform a string into an array of ints, then you can easily make that tool yourself, something like

```
ArrayList<Integer> stringToArray(String v)
{
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
  for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
    char c = v.charAt(i);
    int intVal = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    list.add(intVal);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Making your own functions to change from one object type to another is the best way to go about this.

Comment: Apache's common-convert sounds like what I want: "Most Java applications will require data type conversion, and typically those conversions are hard-coded in the application on an as-needed basis. As an application grows, so do the number of hard-coded conversions. In time, you end up with duplicate code or duplicate conversions that behave differently depending on where they appear in code. Things get worse in enterprise-class applications where data is being exchanged between dissimilar systems and data type conversion gets really complicated."

Comment: But it can't convert my example:-(
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No converter found for java.lang.String->java.util.ArrayList
 at org.apache.commons.convert.Converters.getConverter(Converters.java:122)
 at edu.utexas.hunter.TestRefactor.convertTo(TestRefactor.java:37)
 at edu.utexas.hunter.TestRefactor.main(TestRefactor.java:27)